# How to define a binary variable for each value of i using Pyomo in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, pyomo, stochastic

I have a variable b<sub>i</sub>. `b` is a binary variable which indicates whether to buy a product `i` or not. `i` has a value ranging from 1 to 3.

In mathematical format, the binary variable I want to declare looks like follows:

b<sub>i</sub> ∈ {0, 1} i = 1, 2, 3

I know variable can be declared using following code in Pyomo

```
from pyomo.environ import *
b = Var(domain = Binary)
```

But I am not sure how I can show that `b` is binary only for given values of i. How can I represent the above binary variable for given values using Pyomo in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to declare the index set and then the index set (or multiple sets, if multi-indexed) reference is the first argument to the variable creation.  There are several examples in the dox and this section on [Sets](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_modeling_components/Sets.html).

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

m = pyo.ConcreteModel('example')

m.I = pyo.Set(initialize=[1, 2, 3])
m.b = pyo.Var(m.I, domain=pyo.Binary)

# some nonsense objective...
m.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=sum(m.b[i] for i in m.I))

m.pprint()
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way to do it seems to be as follows:

```
from pyomo.environ import *

model = ConcreteModel()
    
model.i = RangeSet(1,3)
model.b = Var(model.i, domain = Binary)
```